# Unable to access response data from Axios POST method in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am currently facing an issue with the Axios POST method in JavaScript. I'm making a user creation request to an API endpoint, and in the response, I'm expecting to receive the user's name, password, and email. However, I'm having trouble accessing this data from the response to perform further operations.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    createUser = async(data: CreateUser) = >{
  try {
    await agent.createUser.create1(data, data.profilePhoto ! ).then((res) = >{
      //here i destructure result
      const {
        request,
        config,
        data,
        status,
        headers,
        statusText
      } = res;
      runInAction(() = >{
        // #1 here i Save response in userResponse Interface and Console it it shows on console on type of proxy
        this.userResponse = res;
        console.log(this.userResponse ? .data)
      })
      // #2 when i direct console data it gives me all data 
      console.log(data);

    });
    runInAction(() = >{
      this.loadUser({
        pageIndex: 0,
        pageSize: 5
      });
    });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

This is #1 result in console

[image]

and #2

[image: and this #2 Result in Console]

and my agent code is like this

```
create1: (data: CreateUser,file:Blob) =>{
    let formData=new FormData()
    formData.append("profilePhoto",file)
    formData.append("userName",data.userName)
    formData.append("email",data.email)
    formData.append("password",'abc@123')
    formData.append("phoneNumber",data.phoneNumber)
    formData.append("language",data.language)
    formData.append("positionTitle",data.positionTitle)
    formData.append("userRoles",data.userRoles!.toString())
    formData.append("allowedDepartments",data.allowedDepartments!.toString())
    formData.append("allowedSecurityLevels",data.allowedSecurityLevels!.toString())
    formData.append("allowedDocumentType",data.allowedDocumentType!.toString())
    formData.append("departmentId",data.departmentId.toString())
    formData.append("organizationId",data.organizationId.toString())
    return axios.post<CreateUser,any>('/User/CreateUser',formData,{
      headers:{"Content-type":"multipart/form-data"},
    })  

  },
```

And this my interface for storing response data in this

```
 export interface responseCode{
        code:number;
        message:string;  
        data:{
            email:string;
            password:string;
            userName:string;
           
        };
    }
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I try to access the name, password, and email properties from the response.data object, I get undefined values. It seems like I'm not retrieving the user data correctly.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly access the user data from the Axios POST response. Thank you!

Comment: Please stop Writing with Random Upper case letters Like This. It's Very Annoying to read Text Like that -- and now Other People are Fixing your Questions.

Comment: Please rephrase your question - it is unclear where is the problem.

Comment: @LiorPollak i don't get that which letters are anoying the title you mean. By the way i solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i found for this
Was
The interface should arranged with format of resp.data

```
// Before Interface 

export interface responseCode{
        code:number;
        message:string;  
        data:{
            email:string;
            password:string;
            userName:string;
           
        };
    }



//After Correcting
 export interface responseCode{
        code:number;
      
        data:{
            email:string;
            password:string;
            userName:string;
           
        };
        message:string
    }
```

And than inside runinAction
Assign res to userResponse
Like This

```
 //Before code 

 this.userResponse = res;

//after Fixing
this.userResponse = res.data;
```

Thane the response data will be saved in userReaponse
And i access it any where i want.